# Cannot upload game assets to facebook web hosting

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm using facebook web hosting to manage my game assets and I'm receiving an error when uploading a new zip file. It seems the error started right around the whole scandal broke out. Here is the error I'm receiving. "Games must reference one of our supported SDKs via our CDN"

[image]

The weird thing is I am referencing their SDK view their CDN. So I'm not sure what the error is about. I simply have this script tag within the body element of my main page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
```

I'm using version 2.8 of the api. I tried changing the version of the API to 2.12 but that didn't work either. Any idea what could be going on? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This apparently works all of a sudden. I never changed anything in my code. Facebook must of done something to fix.

Comment: The bug was finally fixed.

Answer (score 2):

It's a new facebook bug.

Check out: 
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/369279473553378/

Answer (score 0):

It's a limitation.
Please use the code as below:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
  appId      : '{your-app-id}',
  cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                      // the session
  xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
  version    : 'v2.8' // use graph api version 2.8
});

(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web#example

Comment: I have tried that as well but still no luck. Ran's link suggests that facebook has already fixed it but it still wont allow me to upload. I don't think facebook knows what they are doing in regard to this error message.

Comment: Please find this one [https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1843320132366121/](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1843320132366121/). It's fixed, and I have uploaded assets successful.